# How to manipulate data according to your criteria in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is this possible to change any column entry of a google sheet as shown in the pictures?
Example

[image: How data look like earlier]

I want to change the above entries of Column C to the entries shown in the below picture.

[image: How data look like after]

Please post me a way to do that anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")))
```

[image]